# VB.NET getReturn of dataset always give same string

Tags: vb.net

i have problem with vb.net when i code some script like this

```
 Dim main_class As New query_sync_desktop
 cn = MySQLi.MySQLConnectionMobile
 Query = "SHOW TABLES"
 da = New MySqlDataAdapter(Query, cn)
 ds = New DataSet
 ds.Clear()
 da.Fill(ds, "Tables_in_XXXXX")

 For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
 MyTable = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Item(i).Item(0).ToString()
 MsgBox(MyTable)
 Next
```

it's will be show all the database i have, but when i use for other operation "MyTable" always show the same string.

```
 Dim main_class As New query_sync_desktop
 cn = MySQLi.MySQLConnectionMobile
 Query = "SHOW TABLES"
 da = New MySqlDataAdapter(Query, cn)
 ds = New DataSet
 ds.Clear()
 da.Fill(ds, "Tables_in_XXXXX")

 For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
 MyTable = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Item(i).Item(0).ToString()
 Call main_class.getSyncron()
 Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
MyTable = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Item(i).Item(0).ToString()
```

with this:

```
MyTable = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString
```

Here I assume you just want to see the content of the index 0 for each row.